# How to rename Title site columns in custom content type using powershell

Tags: powershell, content-type, site-column

My requirement is when browser is in English, Title column in Content Type (content type is attached with list) is rename as "Last Name" and when in German, it should be "Nachname". My below code ran successfully and can rename only in English, but I wonder how to rename in German as well.

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("site collection url")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$ct=$web.ContentTypes["CT1"]  
$field = $ct.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title")                            
$ct.FieldLinks[$field.Id].DisplayName ="Last Name"     
$ct.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the *Multilingual User Interface (MUI)*, see a detailed description [here](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/getting-and-setting-language-dependent-field-titles-using-powershell/).

You should use a script like this:

```
function Using-Culture ( 
   [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]   $culture = (throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {…}"), 
   [ScriptBlock] 
   $script = (throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {…}")) 
   { 
     $OldCulture = [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture 
     $OldUICulture = [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture 
         try { 
                 [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture 
                 [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture 
                 Invoke-Command $script 
         } 
         finally { 
                 [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture 
                 [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $OldUICulture 
         } 
   } 

Using-Culture de-DE { 
  $web = Get-SPWeb http://YourSharePointSite
  $ct = $web.ContentTypes["CT1"]
  $fl = $ct.FieldLinks["Title"]
  $fl.DisplayName = "Nachname"
  $ct.Update()
}
```